# Code with XCppRefl does not work

Tags: c++, reflection

I am trying to use XCppRefl lib to achieve reflections in c++. http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/reflcpp/. I could successfully install this library in linux and run the tests given with the source code of the library.

Here is the code that I have written --

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <reflcpp/ClassType_tmpl.hpp>
#include <reflcpp/BoundClassType_tmpl.hpp>
#include <reflcpp/Exceptions.hpp>

using namespace reflcpp;

#include "Complex.h"


int main()
{
    //ClassType ct = ClassType::getClass( string("Complex") );
    ////PtrHolder_smptr_t obj = ct.createInstance();
    //assert(ct.name() == "B");
    Complex x;

    int ret;
    Complex a;

    ClassType c = ClassType::getClass( string("Complex") );

    //cout<<"name :: "<<c.name()<<endl;
}
```

It seems to compile just fine --

```
   $ g++ -g -I /usr/local/include/reflcpp-0.2/ -L /usr/local/include/reflcpp-0.2/ -lreflcpp  main.cpp
```

However when I execute the executable (a.out), I get a core-dump

```
a.out: Type.cpp:87: static const reflcpp::Type_body* reflcpp::Type_body::getType(const std::string&): Assertion `s_class_name_map' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anyone has used this lib before? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to link your main.o to libreflcpp.a . after compiling use this:

```
g++ -p -pg -o"project_name"  ./A.o ./A_reflection.o ./main.o  /usr/local/lib/libreflcpp.a
```